# Where can new cryptocurrency features be found?

Tags: alternatives, altcoin

I was wondering what new cryptocurrency features may be introduced.

How can I find published new cryptocurrency features?

Comment: Put in whatever you can think of.  It's wide open!  There're no rules.  What do *you* want to put in?

Comment: I was just wondering what are the best features that might come along. No personal preference for me.

Comment: Ah, good question!  I'll edit, if you don't mind.  If you're unaware, you can roll it back if you don't like it.  My edit may need an edit, too...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [hardfork wishlist for Bitcoin](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Hardfork_Wishlist). These are changes that are just to hard too do in Bitcoin as they would require major changes to existing infrastructure, but are generally considered good ideas or at least worth experimenting with.